# Update config file with classic ASP

Tags: file, asp-classic

I have a configuration file that i would like to update with classic asp.

Lets say the conf file looks like this:

```
[Parameters]
param1 = 'foo'
param2 = 'boo'
param3 = 'moo'
param4 = 'choo'
```

What I would like to do is write a script to change `param2` and `param4` to have different.

As I am not all that great with asp, I was wondering what would be the best way to do this? ie is there a way I can increment the line and look for `param2` and `param4` and then somehow replace the entire line?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's a way you can random access write a file but you can use the file object to read in a file line by line, check if it's the line you want and if so update it, and write another one out.

```
Dim fs : Set fs = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim file : Set file = fs.OpenTextFile(Server.MapPath("file.config"))
Dim line
Do While Not fs.AtEndOfStream
     line = file.ReadLine()
     If IsThisTheLineIWant(line) Then
         ' some magic
     Else
         ' some hand waving
     End If
Loop
```

Comment: Ha ha. Automatic writing kicked in there I think. Cheers for the spot Anthony.